# I am developing an android app for job search .here i am using PHP as back end

Tags: php, android

in php code when we register automatically create a random code as user id. in  android app  when we save profile information i cant the user id will different. so how to manage user id in all activities and fragment keep same user id until logout help me...............................................  **

Sign up code:

```
<?php
 session_start();

   if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

       include_once("db_connect.php");


    $username = $_POST['user_name'];
    $useremail = $_POST['user_email'];
    $usermobile = $_POST['user_mobile'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];



 function randomstring($len) {
    $string = "";
    $chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    for($i=0;$i<$len;$i++)
        $string.=substr($chars,rand(0,strlen($chars)),1);
    return $string;
    }
    $rndm_code=randomstring(5);




$CheckSQL = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_email='$useremail'";
    $check = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con,$CheckSQL));

          if(isset($check)){

         echo 'Email Already Exist';

          }

 else{


  $Sql_Query = "insert into user (user_id,user_name,user_email,user_mobile,password) values ('$rndm_code','$username','$useremail','$usermobile','$password')";


   if (mysqli_query($con,$Sql_Query)){



  echo 'User Registration Successfully';

 }
 else
 {

 echo 'Try Again';
 }

 }
 }
 mysqli_close($con);

 ?>
```

Android code:

```
 private void registerUser() {
             isConnectingToInternet();
            final String username = signupname.getText().toString().trim();
            final String email = signupemail.getText().toString().trim();
            final String phone = signupphone.getText().toString().trim();
            final String password = signuppassword.getText().toString().trim();


            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(SignupActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Signing Up.. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();


            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Config.URL_REGISTER,
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String ServerResponse) {

                            // Hiding the progress dialog after all task complete.
                            pDialog.dismiss();

                            // Showing response message coming from server.
                            Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, ServerResponse, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {

                            // Hiding the progress dialog after all task complete.
                            pDialog.dismiss();

                            // Showing error message if something goes wrong.
                            Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this,"Check Internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }) {
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() {

                    // Creating Map String Params.
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // Adding All values to Params.
                    params.put("user_name",username);
                    params.put("user_email",email);
                    params.put("user_mobile", phone);
                    params.put("password",password);

                    return params;
                }

            };


            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(SignupActivity.this);


            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);




        }**
```

Comment: **Warning: You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)** and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: **Never store passwords in clear text!**. Only store password hashes! Use PHP's [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) . If you're running a PHP version lower than 5.5 (which I _really_ hope you aren't), you can use the [password_compat library](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) to get the same functionallity.

Comment: Why are you generating random user id's? Why not just use an auto incremented field in the DB as user id? If you do it manually, you also need to check if some other user already has that ID before saving it, or you can end up with two (or more) users having the same user id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server response needs to contain the id in addition to the response text. Usually, this is done by formatting the response as JSON.

Instead of just "User Registration Successfully", the response from the PHP script could be

```
{
  "message":"User Registration Successfully",
  "userId":<your_user_id_goes_here>
}
```

You can use json_encode in PHP to create this format for you from an array.
The code for that would look something like this

```
echo json_encode([
   "message" => "User Registration Successfully",
   "userId" => $rndm_code
]);
exit();
```

It would be good to exit after sending the response so that your JSON deos not becoem invalid by you accidentally echoing something more somewhere later.

In the android app, you would then get the data from the JSON - I am not experienced in android, but I think you would do this by making it a JsonObjectRequest instead of a StringRequest, and then displaying serverResponse.getString("message") and saving serverResponse.getString("userId") as the id in a variable somewhere.

Comment: @IrshadMadappattu I have added a PHP example to the answer (not tested, but it should work)

Comment: @IrshadMadappattu NP - feel fee to ask away if you need more help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50541791/swipe-card-view-id-how-to-send-to-volley-server-when-swipe-right

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
 session_start();

   if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

       include_once("db_connect.php");


    $username = $_POST['user_name'];
    $useremail = $_POST['user_email'];
    $usermobile = $_POST['user_mobile'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];



 function randomstring($len) {
    $string = "";
    $chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    for($i=0;$i<$len;$i++)
        $string.=substr($chars,rand(0,strlen($chars)),1);
    return $string;
    }
    $rndm_code=randomstring(5);




$checkUser = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_email='$useremail' OR user_mobile='$usermobile'";

 $userStatus = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con,$checkUser));

 if(isset($userStatus)){
 die(json_encode(array("success"=>0,"message"=>"Email or Mobile no already exist!!")));
 }
 else
 {

$sql =$con->prepare( "INSERT INTO user(user_id,user_name,user_email,user_mobile,password) VALUES ('$rndm_code','$username', '$useremail', '$usermobile','$password')");
$sql->bind_param("ssss",$rndm_code, $username, $useremail, $usermobile,$password);

if($sql->execute())
{
echo(json_encode(array("success"=>1,"message"=>"Account created successfully!! Please Login")));
}
else
{
die("Something Error".$sql."<br>".mysqli_error($con));
}

 }

}else{

  die(json_encode(array("success"=>0,"message"=>"Empty Request Parameters..!!")));

}
mysqli_close($con);

 ?>
```