# swipe card view id how to send to Volley Server when swipe Right

Tags: android

i'm developing an android app for job search.  i have used Swipe card library for to see jobs like Tinder. here i'm fetching all the job using PHP JSON.
every job has different id. if you want apply job user id and job id sent to server. user id can send to the server using shared preferences. but how to send job id when card swipe right.   i tried lots of way. but it won't work.  please help me. the help will be appreciated..

```
try {

              JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(data);


            arrayList.clear();
            for (int i = 0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){
                getData pd = new getData();
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                pd.setJob_title(jsonObject.getString("job_title"));
                pd.setJob_type(jsonObject.getString("job_type"));
                pd.setJob_description(jsonObject.getString("job_description"));
                pd.setAddress(jsonObject.getString("address"));
                pd.setCity(jsonObject.getString("city"));

                pd.setJob_id(jsonObject.getString("job_id"));




                arrayList.add(pd);

            }
```

Model class

```
public class getData {
    public String job_title = "";
    public String job_description = "";
    public String address = "";
    public String job_type="";
    public String city="";
    public String job_id="";

    public String getJob_description() {
        return job_description;
    }

    public void setJob_description(String job_description) {
        this.job_description = job_description;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getJob_type() {
        return job_type;
    }

    public void setJob_type(String job_type) {
        this.job_type = job_type;
    }

    public String getJob_title() {
        return job_title;
    }

    public void setJob_title(String job_title) {
        this.job_title = job_title;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getJob_id() {
        return job_id;
    }

    public void setJob_id(String job_id) {
        this.job_id = job_id;
    }
}
```

Adapter Class

```
TextView tv_title = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.cardviewjobheading);
        TextView tv_description= (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.cardviewJobDescription);
        TextView tv_jobtype = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.cardviewJobTime);
        TextView tv_companyadress = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.cardviewcompanyname);
        TextView tv_companycity = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.cardviewcompanyaddress);
        TextView tv_jobid=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.cardviewjobid);
        tv_title .setText(data.get(position).getJob_title().toString());
        tv_jobtype.setText(data.get(position).getJob_type().toString());
        tv_description.setText(data.get(position).getJob_description().toString());
        tv_companyadress.setText(data.get(position).getAddress().toString());
        tv_companycity.setText(data.get(position).getCity().toString());
        tv_jobid.setText(data.get(position).getJob_id().toString());
         String  id=data.get(position).getJob_id().toString();
    //    Toast.makeText(context,id,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences(Config.SHARED_PREF_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putString("jobId",id);
        editor.apply();
```

Main Activity

```
@Override
            public void cardSwipedRight( int position) {

                 saveinformation();



            }
private  void saveinformation() {







        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();


        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Config.URL_APPLYJOB,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String ServerResponse) {

                        // Hiding the progress dialog after all task complete.
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(ServerResponse);


                            if (jsonObject.getInt("success") == 0) {

                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), jsonObject.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            } else if (jsonObject.getInt("success") == 1) {
                               // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), jsonObject.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                MaterialToast materialToast=new MaterialToast(MainActivity.this);
                                materialToast.show(jsonObject.getString("message"), ContextCompat.getDrawable(MainActivity.this,R.drawable.toast_drawable),
                                        ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this,R.color.colorAccent),
                                        Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
                                } else

                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), jsonObject.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {


                        pDialog.dismiss();


                        MaterialToast materialToast=new MaterialToast(MainActivity.this);
                        materialToast.show("Check Internet Connection", ContextCompat.getDrawable(MainActivity.this,R.drawable.toast_drawable),
                                ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this,R.color.colorAccent),
                                Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {

                // Creating Map String Params.
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

                // Adding All values to Params.
                SharedPreferences prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(Config.SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                String userid = prefs.getString("userId","");
                String jobid =  prefs.getString("jobId","");





                params.put("user_id",userid);

                params.put("job_id",jobid);

                return params;
            }

        };


        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using SharedPreferance, just use the position you recieved in cardSwipedRight(). Using that position, get the particular item from  arraylist using arraylist.get(position).
Then use that object returned , and get both IDs.
Then pass those values to that volley method.

** Using SharedPreferance for this purpose is not at all recommented.

Comment: job_id is fetching from server is working fine. i want to pass that job id to server